# Eigenvalues of matrix and its transpose.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that if A is a square matrix then A and A transpose have same Eigen values.

Kindly help me how to prove this by generally not considering matrix by ourselves.

Comment: What does "Differentiation" have to do with this question?

Comment: Do you already know any matrix is similar to its transpose?

Comment: sorry,not by differentiation.its wrote wrongly

Comment: I changed the title altogether to make more explicit.

Comment: Now what will be the proof?

Comment: If the answer to DonAntonio's comment is "no", do you know that $\det(B)=\det(B^T)$ for any square matrix $B$?

Comment: dan's answer is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8):

The eigen-values solve $det(A-I\lambda)=0$.  But $det(A^{T}-I\lambda)=det((A-I\lambda)^{T})=det((A-I\lambda))$ by virtue of the nature of the computation of the determinant.  So we may notice that both $det(A-I\lambda)$ and $det(A^T-I\lambda)$ must have the same solutions.  And so the same eigen-values.

Answer (score 3):

$$A\sim A^t\implies \exists\,\text{invertible}\;P\;\;s.t.\;\;P^{-1}AP=A^t\implies$$

$$\det (xI-A^t)=\det(xI-P^{-1}AP)=\det\left[P^{-1}\left(xI-A\right)P\right]=\det(xI-A)\ldots$$

Comment: Why you assume that $A$ and $A^T$ are similar?

Comment: Because it's true.

Comment: Just saying that its not easier problem than original question.

Comment: I've no idea what you know and what you don't, @user52045, and you didn't answer to my question in the comments.

Comment: can you explain it in easier way because I didn't understand it...

Comment: What you didn't understand, @Alikhan ?

Comment: second step..how you write det(xI-a^t)?is it not det(a^t-lamdaI)

Comment: I think answer 2 is more simplest.Isn't?

Comment: Yes, I think definitely dan's answer simpler indeed.